# What is the distribution of the weighted sum of two multivariate normal random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Say we have two multivariate normal random variables $X$ and $Y$ with the same dimensionality, means $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$, and covariance matrices $\Sigma_x$ and $\Sigma_y$. It is possible to show that the distribution of $X+Y$ is also multivariate random normal with mean $\mu_x + \mu_y$ and covariance $\Sigma_x+\Sigma_y$, but what if the distributions are not equally weighted?

Formally, what is the distribution of the sum of $p_xX+(1-p_x)Y$ where $p_x\in(0,1)$ is the proportion of the sum attributable to the distribution $X$?

Comment: What's the distribution of $p_xX$?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent of each other?

Answer (score 1):

Any linear combination of independent multivariate normals of the same dimension is also multivariate normal.  Therefore, if we assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent then

$$Z_p = pX + (1-p)Y \sim \mathcal{N}\left(p\mu_X + (1-p)\mu_Y, p^2\Sigma_X+ (1-p)^2\Sigma_Y\right)$$